# Integral for the Riemann Zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm really struggling to understand the proof that Riemann gave for the analytic continuation of the zeta function. The idea is to take a contour $\gamma$ like the one in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1544309/278029), and integrate
$$\int_\gamma \frac{(-z)^{s-1}}{e^z-1}dz.$$
I have a few questions about this.

First, when we say "infinitesimally" above and below the branch cut, this does mean that we are not literally on the branch cut, correct? I guess I generally don't know what it mean when to integrate "above" and "below" a branch cut.

Second, the usual idea is to assume that $\operatorname{Re}(s)>1$, and take the limit as $\delta\rightarrow 0$; the integral along the circle goes away and then we have the integral (for example, Page 11 [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math185-summer14/gamma-notes.pdf)):
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$$
But are we allowed to deform a contour here and still have the same result? There is no closed loop, so I'm not exactly sure that the resulting contour is still equal to the integral on $\gamma$ per se.

Also, how can we be sure that the integral along what was "infinitesimally" above and below the branch cut converges to the integral literally from $0$ to $\infty$ in the limit?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a branch of $(-x)^{s-1}$ analytic on $\Re(x)>0$ and continue it analytically along your contour. This is always what we mean, in complex analysis, when integrating a function with branch points along a complicated contour. The obtained integral converges absolutely and is holomorphic thus entire (in $s$). For $\Re(s)>1$ we can shrink the contour to $(+\infty,0) \cup (0e^{-2i\pi},+\infty e^{-2i\pi})$ obtaining $2i \sin(\pi s) \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}dx$. Deforming the contour is allowed by the Cauchy integral theorem.

Comment: @reuns Sorry for the late follow-up, but I had a quick question. How would the Cauchy integral theorem work here? We only learned it for closed contours, so should I be thinking about the contour on something like the Riemann sphere? Also, to apply the Cauchy integral theorem, don't we need the contour to be contained in some open set where the function is analytic? When we continue the function to the contour, it seems like such an open set containing the contour can't exist since the contour itself is the "boundary", if that makes any sense.